# What are the characteristic ratios of a number?

Tags: number-theory

The Wikipedia article on the [plastic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_number) says that its characteristic ratios are $\frac{3}{4}$ and $\frac{1}{7}$. Can anyone tell me what is meant by  *characteristic ratio* in this context?  (Using google, I can only find information about the characteristic ratios of polymers - is that related?)

Comment: It looks like this term is being used in a very non-technical way, and is therefore somewhat meaningless. The Wikipedia article talks about *characteristic ratios*; the original source mentions *basic ratios*; but these terms aren't actually defined anywhere, let only explained.

Comment: The Talk page on the Wikipedia article shows that we're not the only people mystified by these words.

Answer (score 1):

**Incomplete answer**

From the [source](http://www.nexusjournal.com/the-nexus-conferences/nexus-2002/148-n2002-padovan.html) of the wikipedia article it seem that it is rather an approximation than an exact value:

> Its basic ratios, **approximately** 3:4 and 1:7, are determined by the lower and upper limits of our normal ability to perceive differences of size among three-dimensional objects.

I don't know anything about the links between math and architecture but it seems that:
$$\frac{1}{\rho} = 0.7548.. \simeq \frac{3}{4}$$
I think that it is the same for $1/7$, some rational function of $\rho$ is close to $0.142...$ and this rationnal function is of importance in architecture.

Comment: I wonder if $1/7$ is related to the fact that $\rho^2 = 1.7548\ldots \approx \frac74$.

Comment: Or $(\rho+1)/(\rho-1) \approx 7.159$, perhaps.